# Multiline EditText crashes app when passing maxlines

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I created a chat activity in my application and at the bottom of the screen, I have an `EditText` where the user writes a message.

Since I don't want the `EditText` to be huge, I limited it to 4 lines and my goal is that in case they write more than 4 lines that it will be scrollable inside the EditText.

My XML is as follows:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_NewComment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/et_less_rounded"
    android:fontFamily="@font/assistant"
    android:gravity="top|start"
    android:hint="@string/ActivityCommunity_PostComment"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="4"
    android:maxLength="5000"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:minLines="1"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="30dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlackText"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

It really grows from 1 line to 4. However, I noticed somce weird case.

I know it probably wont happen in a normal usage but in case I type number (0-9) for more than 4 lines and then touch the EditText, the app crashes and I get the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xx.yy, PID: 18152
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=46; index=46
        at android.text.Layout$HorizontalMeasurementProvider.get(Layout.java:1589)
        at android.text.Layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(Layout.java:1544)
        at android.text.Layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(Layout.java:1454)
        at android.widget.TextView.getOffsetAtCoordinate(TextView.java:11847)
        at android.widget.TextView.getOffsetForPosition(TextView.java:11817)
        at android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:5829)
        at android.widget.Editor.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:1475)
        at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:10056)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12513)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:440)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3400)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:398)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12752)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5106)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4909)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7092)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7061)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7022)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7195)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Are you using an Array in your code? because the error refers to an index out of bounds of the Array.